# Faced unknown characters while trying to change the language of formatted datetime

Tags: php, laravel

I faced the unknown characters when trying to change the language of formatted datetime. So, that unclear characters are 10 �������� 2018 the code behind it is

```
<h6> <?php setlocale(LC_TIME, 'Russian');
        echo $personal->created_at->formatLocalized('%d %B %Y'); ?></h6>
```

I really need your help guys

Comment: I suspect there is an encoding issue, either with your browser, your database, your code or something else altogether. The key to making sure you don't have an encoding issue is that *all* of your systems are set to the same encoding format, end-to-end.

Comment: @Tiffany, hey Tiffany, well in a browser I by default have UTF-8 I dunno how can I ensure that database also have or support UTF-8? :)

Comment: The answer in the question referenced is pretty comprehensive, I recommend having a look at that and reading through it, it should answer your question.